# Make page content visible after a redirect. ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, response.redirect

How can a page show additional content if it is redirected from another page.

I have currently:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" visible="true">
MY NORMAL CONTENT SHOWN AT PAGE LOAD
</asp:panel>

<asp:panel runat="server" visible="false">
A MESSAGE THAT LOADS WHEN THE USER ARRIVES HERE FROM A CERTAIN PAGE
</asp:panel>
```

**QUESTION**

HOW CAN I INVERT THE VISIBILITY OF THE TWO DIVS WHEN THE USER IS SENT HERE FROM ANOTHER PAGE VIA RESPONCE.REDIRECT?

**OR** Alternate suggestions to produce a similar effect.

(In VB please).

Comment: Send any query string value from redirect page , based query string value , you can able to set panel visible to true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ID parameter to your panels (suppose Panel1 , Panel2)

You can simple pass a parameter in the url in the `Response.Redirect("MyPage?ShowPanel=1")`

And read it in the other page :

```
If Request.QueryString("ShowPanel") = "1" Then
Panel1.Visible = False
Panel2.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: Thanks OuSs. This is exactly the conclusion I came to although it was actually grant thomas who pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of possibilities, using a value in the URL or the server Session, for instance. For this example I'd go with a query string value since the content of the page is distinct under certain circumstances, so give it a unique URL. For example, append `?discriminator=value` to the redirect URL.

Comment: Thanks Grant. You answer was my desired solution because it accepts several referrers. I have marked OuSs solution as correct as it best explains the process to future readers of this post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try Request.UrlReferrer
you will get url from where the page is redirected.
you can set your conditions based on that.
if it's null means the page is not redirected from anywhere. the page is opened itself by writing url.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of `Request.UrlReferrer` in your code behind then set the visibility of the panels based on that.